# Received an "Insufficient Privileges" error message when trying to access Account object

Tags: profile, permissions, account, roles

When trying to view an Asset (which is Account standard object) I am getting an error report which says:

> Insufficient Privileges. You do not have the level of access necessary
>   to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

So, I have `Admin` and `Manager` profile, when `Admin` tries to access the `Asset page` then does not have any problem only when I changed the profile to `Manager` then I'm unable to access `Asset page` (is a custom vfp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following might be some considerations to verify this issue.

1. Do they have page level security access (related list on their profile) to the page? - You can also set this for multiple profiles from the page list in setup. Click the "security" link next to the page.
2. Does the page use a standard controller? If so, do your users have Read access to the object (profile)? Can they see the record itself, i.e. is there a private security model on the object they are requesting and don't have read priviliges to the record?

Comment: I'm not admin but would that be possible if you can show me the steps to access to page level security access and security link and lastly, i am using custom vfp so there is no standard controller

Comment: You need to follow below path to access page lavel security for VF pages. Setup --> Manage Users --> Profiles --> Select the Profile --> Visualforce Page Access

Answer (score 1):

Go to Setup search for Profiles -> click on the Manager Profile and make sure following is present:

1.1 Check whether `Asset page` and its controller is available in under *Enable Visual Pages Access* and *Enabled Apex Class Access*.

1.2. Necessary Permission to perform CRUD on Account/Asset object under *Standard Object Permissions*.

1.3. Finally Visibility of the Asset fields used in the page and its controller under *Field-Level Security*